# FLOW_EXCEPTION : Unable to activate journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm facing this issue with journey builder, The validation goes through fine, but the activation fails and displays this error

> FLOW_EXCEPTION;SalesforceObj9361306...... (Decision
> Outcome) - The element has an invalid reference to
> 'new_object.Owner.Contact'.;;FLOW_EXCEPTION;SalesforceObj936.....
> (Decision Outcome) - The element has an invalid reference to
> 'new_object.Owner.Contact.FIELDXX__c'.;; Flow Save failed. Unable to
> activate the Journey, the Sales Cloud user may not have correct
> permissions. Activating a Journey requires the Run Flow and Manage
> Force.com Flow permissions.

I tried :

- recreating the Entry event with fewer filters
- copy an old journey and activate it
- I contacted Salesforce Support, but i still waiting for their feedback

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the SF permissions that the error message mentions: `Sales Cloud user may not have correct permissions. Activating a Journey requires the Run Flow and Manage Force.com Flow permissions`?

Comment: I asked the support team to check, but weirdly I created and activated a journey similar to this one last week.